# C++ class definitions inside header files

Tags: c++, class, header

I'm currently getting started in C++. For the homework I'm currently doing, I have to define  a number of classes in one header file. I'm not sure If I'm doing this right. Here is sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
//classOne.h
class classOne{
    public:
        classOne();
        ~classOne();
        class classInsideClass{
            public:
                classInsideClass
                void hello();
                void print();
        };

}
```

(I have skipped some code in this sample, like constructor for classOne)

```
//classOne.cpp
classOne::classInsideClass::classInsideClass(){}
classOne::classInsideClass::hello(){
    cout << ""Hello <<endl;
}

//main.cpp
classOne callingClass;
callingClass.classInsideClass.hello;
```

I have defined a class inside classOne's header file. And I have created the functions for the this classInsideClass, inside the classOne's cpp. Is this the right way of saying, classInsideClass belongs to classOne, or am I not allowed to do this?

Am I calling the functions of classInsideClass correctly in main.cpp? When I try to run this, I get following error;

> error:invalid use of 'class classOne::classInsideClass

If I don't try and call a function of classInsideClass in main.cpp, it complies fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `void classOne::classInsideClass::hello()`?

Comment: Since hello is a function, I would try callingCall::classInsideClass.hello();

Comment: @Glenn: Use `::` instead of `.` since `classInsideClass` is a class and not an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`classInsideClass` is a *type* inside of `classOne`, not an object. If you want to call `classInsideClass::hello()`, you need an actual *instance* of `classInsideClass`:

```
classOne::classInsideClass callingClass;
callingClass.hello();
```

Comment: ... unless `hello` is declared `static`, which means it does not apply to a particular object and thus has no `this` pointer, in which case it would be called as: `classOne::classInsideClass::hello();`

Comment: And according to the original post, hello is not declared static

Comment: thanks! I see now I made a few typos in my original post, but this was what I was asking. Apologies about the typos, and thankyou for the solution:)

Comment: @user1005253 : In the future, avoid typos by pasting _your actual code_ into your question, and not just some approximation of it. ;-]

Answer (score 4):

```
//classOne.h
...
        class classInsideClass{
            public:
                classInsideClass();
                void hello();
        };
```

Here you've missed the parentehsis at the end of the constructor definition.

```
void classOne::classInsideClass::hello(){
    cout << "Hello" <<endl;
}
```

Here the function return type is missing and the quote marks are supposed to be around the string.

Good luck!

Comment: Opps, I made a few typos in the original post. Sorry about this. I just quickly wrote a sample code. Both of these issue you pointed out does not occur in my original code. Apologies for these mistakes, which effectively wasted other peoples time. Nevertheless thankyou  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
//main.cpp
classOne::classInsideClass internalClassObject;
internalClassObject.hello();
```